# How to transfer browser’s session state across pages?

Tags: javascript, html, shopping-cart, session-state, browser-history

I would like to implement a *client-side* shopping cart bound to the *session history* of the browser. It means that each item added to or removed from shopping cart should create a new session state, and going back or forward in the session history should affect the shopping cart accordingly.

To my knowledge, only the [History API](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/history.html) allows storing data in the session state ([HTTP cookies](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265) and the [Web storage API](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html) store data elsewhere in the browser). So here is a code snippet of a shopping page that allows the user to add items to his shopping cart, to interrupt his activity to go to the home page and resume it later, and to go back or forward in the session history with changes to the shopping cart:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<title>Test</title>
<script>
addEventListener("load", function (event) {
  function setup(data) {
    let element = document.getElementById("data");
    element.textContent = data;
  }
  for (let link of document.links) {
    link.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      let data = history.state || [];
      if (link.href.includes("item=")) {
        data.push(link.textContent);
      }
      history.pushState(data, "", link.href);
      setup(history.state);
    });
  }
  addEventListener("popstate", function (event) {
    setup(event.state);
  });
  setup(history.state);
});
</script>
<p>Control:
  <a href="?home">home</a> <a href="?shop">shop</a>
  <a href="?item=1">item1</a> <a href="?item=2">item2</a>
</p>
<p>Data: <span id="data"></span></p>
</html>
```

To transfer shopping cart data between session states, I have overridden the browser’s default redirection behaviour for click events on all hyperlinks of the page by attaching a click event listener that instead calls the method `history.pushState(data, "", uri)`. This seems to work but these session state transitions do not really change the page, they only change the URI. So for each session state transition I will also have to load the HTML of the target page (here the home page) in the origin page (here the shopping page), which leads to my question:

**How to transfer browser’s session state across pages?**

Comment: Are all the pages on the same domain? Are you trying to share state between tabs?

Comment: @CharlesBamford Yes, they are on the same domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally come up with a solution involving *both* the [History API](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/history.html) and the [Web storage API](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html). For each item added to shopping cart, I store the item in a shopping cart array in the browser’s session storage using the Web storage API, so that the items persist across pages. I also store the item and the length of the shopping cart array in a new session state of the browser’s session history using the History API, so that when the user comes back or forward to this session state I can update the shopping cart array in the browser’s session storage accordingly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<title>Test</title>
<script>
addEventListener("load", function (event) {
  function setup(data) {
    let element = document.getElementById("data");
    element.textContent = data;
  }
  for (let link of document.links) {
    if (link.href.includes("item=")) {
      link.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (!("cart" in sessionStorage)) {
          sessionStorage.cart = JSON.stringify([]);
        }
        let cart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.cart);
        cart.push(link.textContent);
        sessionStorage.cart = JSON.stringify(cart);
        let state = {
          cartLength: cart.length,
          cartItem: link.textContent
        };
        history.pushState(state, "");
        setup(cart);
      });
    }
  }
  addEventListener("popstate", function (event) {
    if (!("cart" in sessionStorage)) {
      return;
    }
    let cart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.cart);
    if (!history.state || cart.length > history.state.cartLength) {
      cart.pop();
      sessionStorage.cart = JSON.stringify(cart);
    } else if (cart.length < history.state.cartLength) {
      cart.push(history.state.cartItem);
      sessionStorage.cart = JSON.stringify(cart);
    }
    setup(cart);
  });
  if (!("cart" in sessionStorage)) {
    return;
  }
  let cart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.cart);
  setup(cart);
});
</script>
<p>Control:
  <a href="?home">home</a> <a href="?shop">shop</a>
  <a href="?item=1">item1</a> <a href="?item=2">item2</a>
</p>
<p>Data: <span id="data"></span></p>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't matter that different tabs can have different carts, or that closing a tab will destroy the cart, checkout the [session storage api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). It stores things in the session.

Comment: As I said, the Web storage API does not use session state (i.e. data stored in the browser’s history), it uses client state.